# MOUSE_DOWN trigger every frame, ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

as I am new to as3,  I want to implement a MachineGun, that fires while has ammo, and the **trigger is pulled**, In my case, the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN`.

The problem is that this event fires only once.

The closest I get is to this is `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE`, but it fails my purpose when the mouse position is sustained

**EDIT:**

I need the updated mouse cursor every frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` event handler you can create an event listener that listens for the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event to be dispatched. Using the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event handler you can repeatedly call a method that handles shooting the bullet. The following is an example I modeled after an example at http://www.benoitfreslon.com/actionscript-throw-bullets-to-mouse-direction:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    [SWF(width="500", height="500", frameRate="24", backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF")]
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _gun:Gun;
        private var _interval:int;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            _gun = new Gun();
            _gun.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - _gun.width / 2;
            _gun.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - _gun.height / 2;
            addChild(_gun);

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onStageMouseDown);

        }// end function

        private function onStageMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onStageEnterFrame);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageMouseUp);

        }// end function

        private function onStageEnterFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            shootBullet();

        }// end function

        private function shootBullet():void
        {
            if (_interval > 5)
            {
                var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet();
                bullet.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onBulletEnterFrame);
                bullet.x = _gun.x;
                bullet.y = _gun.y;
                bullet.angleRadian = Math.atan2(stage.mouseY - _gun.y, stage.mouseX - _gun.x);
                bullet.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onBulletEnterFrame);
                addChild(bullet);

                _interval = 0; // reset

            }// end if

            _interval++;

        }// end function

        private function onBulletEnterFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            var bullet:Bullet = Bullet(e.target);
            bullet.x += Math.cos(bullet.angleRadian) * bullet.SPEED;
            bullet.y += Math.sin(bullet.angleRadian) * bullet.SPEED;

            if ( bullet.x < 0 || bullet.x > 500 || bullet.y < 0 || bullet.y > 500)
            {
                removeChild(bullet);
                bullet.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onBulletEnterFrame);

            }// end if

        }// end function

        private function onStageMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onStageEnterFrame);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStageMouseUp);

            _interval = 0;

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.display.Sprite;

internal class Gun extends Sprite
{
    public function Gun()
    {
        graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
        graphics.endFill();

    }// end function

}// end class

internal class Bullet extends Sprite
{
    public var angleRadian:Number;
    public const SPEED:Number = 10;

    public function Bullet()
    {
        graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
        graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
        graphics.endFill();

    }// end function

}// end class
```

The point of interest is in the `onStageEnterFrame()` method. There's an `if` statement that checks whether the `_interval` property's value is greater than 5, if so, a new bullet is created and shot otherwise the `_interval` property's value is incremented. The purpose of the `_interval` property is to space out the bullets being shot.

**[UPDATE]**

Here is an image of the example flash application running:

[image]

The mouse button is being held down in the top right corner hence the bullets being shot in that direction.

Answer (score 3):

On receiving a MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN event, run a while loop making the machine gun fire.  The loop breaks on receiving a MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP event.  Something like this

```
private function handleMouseDown( event:Event ):void
{
   this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP , handleMouseUp );
   startFiring();
}


private function handleMouseUp( event:Event ):void
{
    this.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP , handleMouseUp );
    this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN , handleMouseDown);
   stopFiring();
}
```

EDIT: For clarification, the stop and start firing functions are functions that run a loop to keep the machine gun firing animation going however that may be.

Comment: I also need the updated cursor position, so i may know where the shot is going to, how do I get that?

Comment: @Fabiano, Add a listener on `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` that calls `aim(event.stageX, event.stageY)`

Answer (score 0):

add firing action to ENTER_FRAME event when mouse is pressed and remove when mouse is up

```
this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.handler_down );
this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.handler_up );

private function handler_down(event:Event):void {
  super.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.handler_frame );
}

private function handler_up(event:Event):void {
  super.removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this.handler_frame );
}

private function handler_frame(event:Event):void {
  this.fire();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to do this regularly, and instead of using an enter_frame listener, I opt for a Timer() and TimerEvent.Timer listener. That way I have more control over how often the repeat is fired without accounting for frame rate and what not.

```
    private var fireRepeat:Timer;
    private function triggerDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if (!this.fireRepeat) {     // create the repeater
            this.fireRepeat = new Timer(500, 0);
            this.fireRepeat.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, this.fire);
        }
        fire();                     // fire the first bullet
        this.fireRepeat.reset();    // reset the repeater
        this.fireRepeat.start();    // start the repeater
    }
    private function triggerUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if (this.fireRepeat) { this.fireRepeat.stop(); }
    }
    public function fire(e:* = null):void {
        trace('fire!');
    }
```